# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort - can IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK be configured?

Tags: .net, serial-port

I've been trying to learn a bit about how .Net (3.5) interacts with the Serial port through the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPorts` class by writing a small Windows Forms application to gather caller display data from an old external modem.

I've tested that the modem supports caller display; using Putty or Hyperterminal I can configure the modem to collect caller display data (using the command `AT#CID=1`, which I found [here](http://ftp.mtnsys.com/Pages/howto/htmdmtst.htm)), and when the phone rings, the data is displayed. In the terminal window, it looks like this:

```
RING

DATE = 0308
TIME = 2045
NMBR = 01234567890

RING
```

My C# application appears to successfully configure the modem and displays a `RING`
message when the phone rings; however, it never displays the caller ID data.

In an effort to understand why this is, I compared the actions taken by the different clients using Sysinternals [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx).

The primary difference appears in the connection configuration; my C# application includes the following line, which Putty and Hyperterminal do not;

```
0.00000307  callerID.exe    IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK  Serial0 SUCCESS Mask: RXCHAR RXFLAG CTS DSR RLSD BRK ERR RING
```

As I understand it, `IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK` is an inclusive list of message types to filter for.

So, three questions:

Is it possible that the caller ID information is being suppressed by `IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK`?

If so, how can I configure it to show the caller ID info? It doesn't appear to be accessible from the class properties.

If I can't configure it, is my only option to get around this to write my own wrapper to the lower-level system functions controlling the serial port?

My understanding of serial port communications is very basic, so I expect I'm way off in my diagnosis. Any guidance gratefully received.

Comment: You made a really good job keeping this up-to-date while answering your own question! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was way off with my diagnosis.

It seems that the `WriteLine` method doesn't terminate the commands it sends with the line terminator my modem is expecting.

All I needed to do was add a carriage return to the commands I am sending, and send them using the `Write` method.

Apologies for wasting anybody's time.

Comment: yeah, its necessary to add newline in the method     _serialPort.WriteLine("at#cid=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301786.aspx) on MSDN which looks like a decent example of how to access the serial port via P/Invoke on the system dll's.

I'd still like to know if I can get around my issues with the .Net class.